# Listing sent mails - cannot connect to domain

Tags: php, email, imap, pop3

I develop a progam to read inbox and sent emails.I tested it with localhost.It is successfull.But when it uploaded to server,only inbox is working.With Sent it shows the following message.

> '/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX.Sent' Cannot connect to domain:Can't open
>   mailbox .

But with the following hostname it is working.

```
/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX
```

when using `INBOX.Sent` it is not working?

I will appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Not all servers name their folders identically. Have you listed the folder names?

Comment: yes.it is INBOX.Sent

Comment: When testing with localhost, list of folders are : {server.domain.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX {server.domain.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX.test {server.domain.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX.Sent  {server.domain.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX.Trash {server.domain.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX.Junk  {server.domain.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX.Drafts          But testing in my website it shows only one folder {server.domain.com:995/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX

Comment: solved.In website i tested with pop3.I changed that to imap.